# Why do aircraft fly over Paris when they're forbidden from doing so?

Tags: regulations, airspace, france

I though aircraft were forbidden to fly over Paris, but I can hear a lot of planes flying over Paris, and, looking at Flightradar24, they *are* really flying over the city.

They are commercial planes, not military or private ones.

Do you know if the regulations surrounding this have changed, or if it's just something normal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a map from [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/) with the airspace around Paris:

[image: Paris Airspace]

You can see several major airports like Charles De Gaulle and Le Bourget to the North East and Orly to the South. In the center, there is a region marked **LFP-23**. This is the restricted airspace you probably had in mind. The [French AIP](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dvd/eAIP_14_JUL_2022/FRANCE/AIRAC-2022-07-14/html/index-fr-FR.html) defines it as follows:

> **LF P 23 PARIS**
>
> SFC to 6500ft AMSL
>
> Excluding LF-P 47 BALARD, which retains its status.
> CAG/CAM: prohibited penetration, including unmanned aircraft, with the exception of:
>
> - after agreement of the Préfecture de Police de Paris, aircraft on mission of emergency medical service, civil security, gendarmerie, state transport customs and defense for which bypassing is not compatible with the execution of the mission ;
> - defence aircraft on air security missions (notification to the Préfecture de Police de Paris as soon as possible) ;
> - aircraft that have applied for entry to the police headquarters in Paris at least five working days before the date of the flight and have obtained formal authorization ;
> - aircraft authorised by the Paris-Issy-les-Moulineaux Heliport Control Authority (LFPI) which follow departure and arrival procedures published by means of aeronautical information ;
> - twin-engine helicopters, in the event of engine failure at the take-off of the Paris-Issy-les-Moulineaux heliport (LFPI) in accordance with the regulations in force ;
> - flights authorised in accordance with the procedures described in AIP ENR 1.2 and aeronautical chart 1/100 000 "Itineraires Hélicoptères" in CTR PARIS (appendix of 8 February 1984 decree).

You therefore shouldn't see any commercial aircraft flying in this restricted airspace below 6500 ft AMSL. Above that and outside of the marked region, the restriction does not apply.

Comment: (+1) Note that the marked region roughly corresponds to what the locals consider to be Paris proper, the municipality of Paris (without the Bois de Vincennes and the Bois de Boulogne).

Comment: Also, just as a note for those not particularly familiar with commercial aviation: For commercial aircraft departing CDG, getting above 6,500' before getting to central Paris will definitely not be a problem. For example, at this particular moment, there is an AF flight from CDG to GNV that was passing 11,000' as it entered LFP-23. A DHL aircraft passing through the area from Casablanca on the way into CDG was still above 12,000'. The 6,500' rule more just keeps low-flying sightseeing flights and general aviation away from the city.

Comment: what's lfp 47? it's marked with same green color in same green circle-ish blob as lfp 23

Comment: It also looks like the entire CZ is in LFR-205

Comment: @NooneAtAll LFP-47 is listed as "BALARD: SFC to 2000 ft AMSL, **Defence facilities**, Entry prohibited for all ACFT, including unmanned aircraft except for twin-engines HEL, in case of failure of engine for take off from HLP Paris-Issy-les-Moulineaux according to the regulatory requirements in force." So there are fewer exception for flying in this airspace compared to the surrounding LFP-23.

Comment: @NooneAtAll: P47 includes the [Defense ministry and Armed forces HQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagone_Balard). The green area behind in the article picture is Issy public heliport mentioned by Bianfable, and, visible on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sha8G.jpg), between them the beltway around Paris "intra-muros" (within fortifications). Paris, which delineates P23. Entering P23 (ambulances are allowed) requires a twin-turbine helicopter, but P47 is prohibited (including rotorcraft) except emergencies for rotorcraft taking off from Issy and experimenting a turbine failure.

Comment: @StephenS: R 205/2, /3, etc delineate [Paris TMA at different altitudes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbiJc.png).